# ng-if does't hide the second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have two controllers per two views and one service. Service object stores the selected value from the first view. Based on this selected value `ng-if` must render either one  element on the second view. Here is my code that should perform this task.

Controller for the first view:

```
gasStation.controller('registrationController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$window', 'customerType', function ($scope, $log, $http, $window, customerType) {
    customerType.setCustomerType($scope.customerType);
    url += '/pages/index.html#' + '/dashboard';
    $window.location.href = url;
    $scope.customerType = customerType.getCustomerType();
    console.log(customerType.getCustomerType() + ' customer type from controller');};}]);
```

First view:

```
    <div class="site-content">
        <h1 class="fueling-header">Registration</h1>

        <form name="regForm" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
            <fieldset>

                <!--<%--Type of customers--%>-->
                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label for="customerTypes">Your group</label>
                    <select id="customerTypes" ng-model='customerType'>
                        <option value="REGULAR">Regular</option>
                        <option value="BUSINESS">Business</option>
                    </select>
                    <label id="groupError" class="error"/>
                    {{customerType}}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    <!--END: register page-->
```

Second controller

```
gasStation.controller('dashboardController', ['$scope', '$log', 'customerType', 
function ($scope, $log, customerType) {
    $scope.customerType = customerType.getCustomerType();
    $scope.isBusiness = (customerType.getCustomerType() === 'BUSINESS');
    $scope.isRegular = (customerType.getCustomerType() === 'REGULAR');
    console.log($scope + ' dashboard controller');}]);
```

Second view:

```
<div id="menu">
     <div class="pure-menu menu-width-restricted">
        <span class="pure-menu-heading">
            <a href="/">GSS <img src="/resources/img/gss-icon.png" width="24" height="24"/></a>
        </span>

        <ul class="pure-menu-list">                                  

        <li class="fixed-height">
        <br/>

        <div class="pure-menu-link">
            Hello, {{customerType}}
        </div>

        <div ng-if="isRegular">

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/business_dashboard" class="pure-menu-link">{{customerType == 'REGULAR'}}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/business_dashboard" class="pure-menu-link">Revenue</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_gasstations" class="pure-menu-link">Stations</a>
            </li>

        </div>

        <div ng-if="isBusiness">

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/search_gasstations" class="pure-menu-link">Search</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_fuelings" class="pure-menu-link">Fuelings</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_vehicles" class="pure-menu-link">Vehicles</a>
            </li>

        </div>

        <br/>
        </li>

        <li class="fixed-height">
        <hr/>
        </li>
        <br/>
        <li class="fixed-height">
        <a href="#/logout" class="pure-menu-link">Log Out</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select the REGULAR type customer from the drop down on the first view then on the second view   `<div ng-if="isRegular"></div>` is being displayed and `<div ng-if="isBusiness"></div>` is not being displayed.

The problem is when I select BUSINESS type customer from the first view then both `<div ng-if="isBusiness"></div>` and `<div ng-if="isRegular"></div>` are being displayed simultaneously. But I would like to display only  `<div ng-if="isBusiness"></div>`

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Screenshot of the stack trace when I select the regular customer: 
[image]

When I select the business type customer:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could explain why such layout renders properly based on the boolean values from dashboard controller.

```
<div id="menu">
 <div class="pure-menu menu-width-restricted">

    <div ng-if="isRegular()">
        <span class="pure-menu-heading">
            <a href="/">GSS <img src="/resources/img/gss-icon.png" width="24" height="24"/></a>
        </span>

        <ul class="pure-menu-list">                                  

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <br/>

            <div class="pure-menu-link">
                Hello, {{customerType}}
            </div>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/search_gasstations" class="pure-menu-link">Search</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_fuelings" class="pure-menu-link">Fuelings</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_vehicles" class="pure-menu-link">Vehicles</a>
            </li>

            <br/>

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <hr/>
            </li>

            <br/>

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <a href="#/logout" class="pure-menu-link">Log Out</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div ng-if="isBusiness()">
        <span class="pure-menu-heading">
            <a href="/">GSS <img src="/resources/img/gss-icon.png" width="24" height="24"/></a>
        </span>

        <ul class="pure-menu-list">                                  

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <br/>

            <div class="pure-menu-link">
                Hello, {{customerType}}
            </div>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/business_dashboard" class="pure-menu-link">Revenue</a>
            </li>

            <li class="fixed-height">
                <a href="#/view_gasstations" class="pure-menu-link">Stations</a>
            </li>

            <br/>

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <hr/>
            </li>

            <br/>

            <li class="fixed-height">
            <a href="#/logout" class="pure-menu-link">Log Out</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you edit your selection, your $scope.customerType is changed, not necessarily your customerType.getCustomerType() method.
I'm not sure why yours isn't working, since I don't know what getCustomerType() does exactly.

```
    $scope.customerType = customerType.getCustomerType();
    $scope.isBusiness = (customerType.getCustomerType() === 'BUSINESS');
    $scope.isRegular = (customerType.getCustomerType() === 'REGULAR');
```

Did you check for errors in your console? It might not evaluate ng-if and just show both if some error occurred.

Comment: I put console log at the 2nd controller. What I see is: 1. service object correctly transfers the information from the first view, 2. $scope for the 2nd controller contains the customer type. But still, the ng-if doesn't work properly. PS I have added a screenshot for the stack trace.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your registration controller.
You're redirecting immediately inside the controller?

It seems that if you change your selection in that registration view, nothing is happening. Given your code.

Comment: Yes, I do an immediate redirect in my registration controller. I have solved my problem. It seems that the problem was in my dashboard view.

Comment: I cannot explain why such mark-up works properly for me. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Your ng-if creates a child scope, which  means that the customerType variable might not be equal in all scopes at all time.

I would try to output the value of customerType in your previous way to see what's going on. Your current solution is not desired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92570/discussion-between-noppey-and-mr-m).